# Problem with Facebook Login : ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Tags: php

I'm using facebook login for my website (non SDK), but when user logins, it keep showing the error : ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

I break the code :

```
$facebook_profile_uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;
echo $facebook_profile_uri;
die();
```

The website will show the URL, then I copy the URL, paste it on another tab, I can receive the information from facebook.

But if I redirect user like this :

```
$facebook_profile_uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $facebook_profile_uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Get user information
$user = json_decode($response);
```

The only thing I receive is : ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your `redirect URL` at `Facebook` console

First go to  `Advanced` tab inside `Settings`

[image]

There after scroll down to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

register your `url` there the moment you will save changes it will stop giving this exception

[image]

Comment: I've already registered. If not, I cannot receive the access token.